# A question on discriminant analysis- Linear discriminant function

Tags: self-study, classification, multivariate-analysis, discriminant-analysis

[image]

[image]

Above is part of an examination paper. I am not sure how to understand this SAS output. Especially what is there in the last table which looks to me like two discriminant functions. Can someone help me understand this? And how do I use this to classify given some observation say $X_1=94$, $X_2=491$? Thanks

Comment: @ttnphns One way I know is checking the sign of b'x-k and depending on the sign the population is chosen. Is this the same or different?

Comment: Was that homework or solving textbook exercises? If yes, please add `self-study` tag.

Comment: This was from a past paper on Multivariate data analysis. I will add the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last table shows **Fisher's discrimination & classification coefficients**. [Here is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31384/3277) how they are computed (see the bottom section). When groups are only 2, LDA is called "Fisher's LDA", and extracting *discriminant function* and then classifying by it can be done in one stage: there is no actual need to extract the discriminant function bodily and then classify by it, - the equivalent pass is to compute Fisher's coefficients, which allow to classify data directly by the original variables.

So no, the table is not `two discriminant functions`. For 2 groups, only **one** disriminant function exist. That function is actually not shown anywhere in your output: it is implied.

To assign an observation with the help of the Fisher's coefficients, compute `classA = .36*X1+.39*X2-101.70` and `classB = .49*X1+.34*X2-97.43`. Compute `classA-classB`. If the value is positive, assign to A; if negative, assign to B.

Nowadays, Fisher's coefficients are rarely used, mostly for didactic reasons, for they conceal the computation of the discriminant function(s) as a latent variable(s). LDA is theoretically two-stage analysis: [extract](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277) discriminants, then [classify](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31384/3277) by them via Bayes' approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In addition what do you think of the question asking whether this is an accurate classification rule? any ideas?

Comment: `(39+44)/90=92% correct rate` is high for me.

Comment: @Heisenberg  I have a question regarding LDA/FDA. Let say, original dataset: 100 features/dimensions; 2 classes; 50 samples/examples. `We start with n dimensions and end with k dimensions, where k < n.` and is not restricted to only 2 output value. Is that correct?