# Calculate the Fisher discriminant value for Fisher projection in R

Tags: r, classification, discriminant-analysis

I am running an LDA model on the iris dataset for two class (any two).

I want to now calculate the Fisher discriminant value for Fisher projection.

Does this mean I need the svd value?

Comment: Are you speaking of discriminant functions values or of Fisher's classification functions values? (See footnote here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/190821/3277 about terminologic confusions)

Comment: Fisher's classification functions because the task is for classification

Comment: OK then, there in the answer is the link to another answer showing formulas how those can be computed (at least, SPSS does so, I believe other programs are doing same way).

Comment: Ah, here is the direct link. Look under "Addition". https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31384/3277

Comment: Actually the confusion is all I am asked to do is calculate the Fisher discriminant value for Fisher projection. There is no further explaination

Comment: But this time you sound like you want to compute discriminant function values. For 2 class aka Fisher's LDA. There is a number of answers on this site showing it. Did you try a search?