# Understanding Bayes’ Theorem in Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)

Tags: bayesian, discriminant-analysis

I am reading *An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R* by *Trevor Hastie* and I have reached Chapter 4 Section 4: Linear Discriminant Analysis. In this section, the author reaches a formula and I can’t quite follow how he got there. Can someone clarify it for me? Here is the passage that precedes the equation.

[image]

[image]

I know that Bayes’ theorem states that P(A|B) = P(A)P(B|A) / P(B).
I do not understand why he uses that expression for P(B)

Comment: In terms of your example, $\pi_k$ is P(A) and $f_k(x)$ is P(B|A), which is given that Y is in kth class, probability that X=x. Denominator is just marginal for X, i.e., probability X=x considering all possible classes.

Comment: Thanks, I see that. However, I do not understand why he would use that as P(B). From what I understand, P(B) here is P(X=x). Why would that equal the expression above?

Comment: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31366/3277

Comment: The link shared by @ttnphns seems to be very thorough and insightful. That should clarify ur doubt.

Comment: Yes, thank you @ttnphns for that link. It explains everything very clearly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked quickly at the link and didn't see the most direct explanation, but might have skimmed too fast. Expanding "$P(B)$" in this way uses the law of total probability. The idea is that if you have a partition of the sample space, the we can find $P(B)$ by summing up the probability parts of $B$ found in each of the partitions. A partition just means that we have split the sample space in such a way that each point can be found in exactly one of the partitions or groupings.

In your case, each observation is assumed to be in exactly one of the $K$ classes, i.e the classes are your partition. They say there is a discrete random variable $Y$ which represents membership to the $k$th class. The event that an observation belongs to the kth class is then simply $\{Y=k\}$.

The law of total probability can be shown as follows for arbitrary $B \subseteq \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. (or more formally $B \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the appropriate sigma algebra).

\begin{align*}
P(B) &= P(B \cap \Omega)\\
&= P(B \cap (\cup_{i=1}^K\{Y =i\}))\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^KP(B\cap \{Y =i\})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^K P(B|\{Y =i\})P(\{Y =i\})\\
\end{align*}

The third line follows because the events are disjoint (no overlap between the classes) and the last line follows from the multiplicative rule of probability.

Notice that $P(Y = i)$ is just the weight $\pi_i$ for class i. Similarly, in your text they denote $P(X=x|Y=k) = f_k(x)$ to be the probability of $X=x$ given it is in class K if $X$ is discrete or the probability density of $X$ given membership in class K if it is continuous. (Not shown, but the law of total probability can be extended to the continuous case when we are working with densities).

Now why do we do this? The answer is because it is easier in the set up given by the problem. The classifier model assumes a density for each class $f_i(x)$, but not a density for the observations in general, $f(X=x)$. So to figure out the density $f(X=x)$ it is much easier to split this up into the classifier densities and the law of total probability gives us a way to do that, by simply summing the classifier densities weighted by how likely they are to occur. This technique is so useful and common that in many elementary probability texts Bayes rule is expressed directly in the partition form (usually for say partition into event $A$ and its complement, $A^c$.).

Comment: Thank you! This is a direct and clear answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

@ttnphns shared this link that contains the answer:
[Linear discriminant analysis and Bayes rule: classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31366/3277)

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality 
statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?