# Pooled within-class matrix in linear discriminant analysis: why does det(S) = 1?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, discriminant-analysis

I am deriving likelihoods of class membership after LDA dimensionality reduction.

I understand from ttnphns's answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31366/linear-discriminant-analysis-and-bayes-rule-classification) that the pooled covariance matrix between discriminants is the identity matrix, allowing for simplification of the multivariate normal distribution from

$$f(x|k)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k |{\textbf S}|}} * e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k)^\top \textbf S ^{-1}(x-\mu_k)}$$
to the simpler
$$f(x|k)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k}} * e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k)^\top \textbf (x-\mu_k)}$$

where ${\textbf S}$ is the pooled covariance matrix between the discriminants and $\mu_k$ is the centroid of some class $k$.

Why the identity matrix? It's not obvious to me, and simulating (based on my understanding of LDA) doesn't return this result.

```
w = rand(3)+eye(3); % simulated data
b = rand(3)+eye(3); % simulated data
W = w*w'; % some random pooled within-class covariance
B = b*b'; % some random between-class covariance
[V, eigenvalues] = eig(inv(W)*B);
eigenvalues = diag(eigenvalues);
[eigenvalues, indx] = sort(eigenvalues, 'descend');
V = V(:, indx); % the ordered discriminants
cov(V)
```